# How to setup locales for Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

i have a rather specific setup regarding rails internationalization. I'm using `rails-i18n` gem, but that shouldn't matter. It worked perfectly with Rails 3. Here is my config from `config/application.rb`

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :en
config.i18n.locale = :hr
```

Let me explain:

- locale is set to `:hr` (Croatian) because I mostly make localized applications in Croatian language
- default locale is set to `:en` because I'm often using gems like `rails-admin` which have English translations included. It plays nicely in production where missing (Croatian) translations fallback to English. That's fine, all admins understand English :)

### And the question is: how to make it work with Rails 4?

It seems that Rails 4 ignores `config.i18n.locale`, and it always use `:en` locale.

So far, I've been using `before_action` to set `I18n.locale = :hr` but that doesn't work in Rails console or Rack middleware...

Thanks in advance,

Danijel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple solution and I'm posting it here...

Insert into `config/application.rb`

```
  config.i18n.default_locale = :hr
  config.i18n.available_locales = [:hr, :en]
  config.i18n.fallbacks = [:en]
```

Remove or comment the following line from `config/environments/production.rb`

```
  # config.i18n.fallbacks = true
```

or change it to:

```
  config.i18n.fallbacks = [:en]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the code below:

```
class ApplicationController
    ...

    before_filter :set_locale

    ...

    private

    def set_locale
        I18n.locale = :hr
    end 

end
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm already doing that. But that doesn't work in Rails console or Rack middleware...

Comment: And if you move `I18n.locale = :hr` to initializer?